# is there any direct way to remove \xa0 from the output while web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Code:

```
date = [item.find(class_='wr-date__light').get_text() for item in items]
```

Ouput:

```
['31st\xa0January', '1st\xa0February', '3rd\xa0February', '4th\xa0February', '5th\xa0February', '6th\xa0February', '7th\xa0February', '8th\xa0February']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string replacement to remove the characters. And you can use `map` to apply that to every element of the list.

```py
date = list(map(lambda s: s.replace('\xa0', ''), date))
```

If you are not comfortable using `lambda` expressions, you can define a new function.

```py
def replace(text):
    return text.replace('\xa0', '')

date = list(map(replace, date))
```

Comment: Why do you need to do all these when you can simply write this `date = [item.find(class_='wr-date__light').get_text().replace('\xa0','') for item in items]` right?

Comment: \xa0 is a non breaking space in latin1 so it should be replaced with space

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster thanks